# AVPlayer causes Simulator to crash but runs fine on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I've searched all the Internet around, but found no mentions of this error.

I am using AVPlayer to play stream audio from remote or local URL.
However, while on my device it works fine, on simulator it is crashing.

I've found out that creation of player is going fine, but as soon as I call [playerInstance play] the app crashes.

The error is occurring somewhere in CommonURLAssetNotificationQueue.
And the exception breakpoint points me to 0x10e8a2519:  pushq  %rbp, which is not helpful at all.

However, on device it works fine.

So, is it my mistake and I have to fix the code? Or it's just simulator acting wonky?

Comment: I have also always had a problem playing files with the AVPlayer on the simulator. I think this is a problem of the simulator. Never had problems with it on actual devices.

Comment: when you say stream audio, do you strictly mean HLS as opposed to an audio file located on a remote server?

Comment: I think I meant strewing as streaming from audio file on remote server.

Comment: Strangely enough, after disabling and re-enabling Auto Layout the issue is no more.

Comment: And the issue surfaced again. Strange enough, it happened right after I've added constraints to the Storyboard.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is likely that you have an exception breakpoint enabled. The play method in AVPlayer normally throws an exception, even though nothing is wrong. The exception doesn't crash the app, and the app then continues to run exactly as you wanted it to. If you have exception breakpoints enabled, however, Xcode notices the exception and crashes the app. If you go into the left sidebar and disable your exception breakpoint the app will run without crashing.

Comment: You're right! After disabling breakpoints, I can finally test music playing in simulator. Thank you! This is the best way to start my day.

Comment: Wow... Good going Apple. AVPlayer just always throws an exception? That's some sweet tech.

Comment: dude, you are amazing ;)

Comment: This was killing me, just never googled the right question! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Change exception all as Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

My resolving method is to add 'usage description' in App's Info page. Because the AVPlayer Demo App is trying to use local photo library without asking permission, this causes the demo app to crash. After adding the 'Privacy — Photo Library Usage Description', I can run this demo app successfully.